# Getting NULL value at the end while writing to the file

Tags: java, io

I have problem while writing to the file.  I want to write contents of my input file to output file but while writing to the file, I am getting NULL value written at the end of file.

What's the reason behind that?

My code is:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;


 public class FileReading {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FileInputStream fi=new  
  FileInputStream("E:\\Tejas\\NewData_FromNov\\New_Folder\\bb.txt");
    DataInputStream di=new DataInputStream(fi);

    BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(di));
    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("E:\\Tejas\\NewData_FromNov\\New_Folder\\Out_bb.txt");
    int ss;

    byte[] input=new byte[500];
    int len=input.length;

    while((ss=di.read(input,0,len))!=-1)
    {
        System.out.println(ss);
        //fout.write(ss);
        fout.write(input,0,len);

    }
    fout.close();

}

 }
```

Comment: Do you mean the byte 0x00, or the string "NULL"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're always writing out the full buffer, even if you've only read part of it because the third argument to `write` is `len` (the length of the buffer) instead of `ss` (the number of bytes read). Your loop should look like this:

```
int bytesRead; // Easier to understand than "ss"
byte[] buffer = new byte[500];

while((bytesRead = di.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
{
    System.out.println(bytesRead);
    fout.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Additionally:

- You should close both the input and output streams in `finally` blocks to ensure they're *always* closed (even if there's an exception).
- You don't need a `DataInputStream` - just a `FileInputStream` is fine here.
- You're not using your `BufferedReader` at all.
- Consider using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) or a similar third-party library which contains utility methods to do all of this.

Comment: A sage reminder to check file size of input against output files.

Answer (score 3):

The read method returns the number of actually read bytes, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached. So you should only write ss bytes, and not len bytes:

```
while ((ss = di.read(input, 0, len)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(ss);
    fout.write(input, 0, ss);
}
```

Note thet the DataInputStream and the BufferedReader are completely unnecessary here.